# How to use tickInterval: Number in Highcharts with the Minimum and Maximum values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to use tickInterval: Number in Highcharts with the Minimum and Maximum values

I have to show the only 3 value in my y-axis but present i'm getting 5 values in my y-axis .

```
xAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 1
},

yAxis: {
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false
},
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/cscp8yef/)

Comment: startOnTick: _Whether to force the axis to start on a tick. Use this option with the maxPadding option to control the axis start. Defaults to true_ .So  what you want **years**  **values**

Comment: what are the three values, i am not getting at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tickInterval` attribute may be helpful to you (see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickInterval).

In your case, if you want only three values in your y-axis, you'll need to figure out the lowest (minimum) and highest (maximum) values that are plotted on that axis, and then set a value for `tickInterval` that shows only three lines.

Here's an example using your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/cscp8yef/7/

```
yAxis: {
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false, 
    min: -10, 
    max: 120, 
    tickInterval: 50
},
```

I used `min` and `max` to force the start and end values of your y-axis and used `tickInterval` to show the correct number of lines.

Here's the result:

[image]

For your type of chart (bubble), setting both `startOnTick` and `endOnTick` to false may be useful for making sure the bubbles have enough room to draw.

I hope all this is useful for you!